# How to get google places api to return nearby hotels

Tags: google-places-api

I'm trying to put together a google places call to do a nearby search just for hotels. I tried using the types parm but the closest type to hotel I found was lodging which produced no results. So then I tried using the name parm and the same zero result. Am I missing something or is places not meant to perform a search of this type. I increased the radius to a number I'm certain that there are other hotels (2 should have been fine).

//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.800870,-96.830803&radius=25&name=Marriot%20Sheraton%20W&key=

Result from call:

```
{
  html_attributions: [ ],
  results: [ ],
  status: "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The radius of 25m appears to be too small and the name is not a subset of any place names in the area.  Were you trying to get any places with a name of Marriot, Sheraton, or W?  I don't believe the implementation works that way and instead it looks for a place with "Marriot Sheraton W" in the name.

If you change radius to 400 and name to Sheraton, then you do get the nearby "Sheraton Suites Market Center Dallas".

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.800870,-96.830803&radius=400&name=Sheraton&key=[key]](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.800870,-96.830803&radius=400&name=Sheraton&key=%5bkey%5d)

Comment: Thank you! I was thinking the radius was in km. I understood the places api doco to state the name parm could have multiple values separated by a space(https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). I went back to using the type=lodging and a valid value in meters: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=32.800870,-96.830803&radius=8046&types=lodging&key=<key> Thanks @pushbit

Comment: I believe if there are multiple words, then all of them must be found somewhere in the name (or associated names).  For example, `Sheraton Market Center` will still return the above place, but `Sheraton Foo Market Center` will not.